Pull a Docker image from a remote repository with Ansible
I am trying to perform this bash command via Ansible on a remote host, leveraging Ansible modules:
docker pull example.com/some/path/to/image:sometag
Note, if I perform the above command on the device, it runs fine.
I know I can use shell and call it a day, but tend to shy away from abstracting what is happening from Ansible.
I figured this was a common use-case, but all attempts to do something I thought would be fairly straight forward has only resulted in errors.
Some examples of what I have tried:
- name: Pull down file_ingest_agent
  community.docker.docker_image_pull:
    name: example.com/some/path/to/image:{{ file_ingest_agent }}
    platform: amd64

This results in an error stating:

fatal: []: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3.8"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Error pulling image example.com/some/path/to/image:sometag - 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=sometag&fromImage=example.com%2Fsome%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fimage&platform=amd64: Internal Server Error ("unknown: repository some/path/to/image not found")"}

It seems like it a 500 from localhost?  Also, it seems to cut off the URL of the repository, stating that repository some/path/to/image not found.
Also tried:
- name: run container
  docker_image:
    repository: example.com/some/path/to/image:{{ file_ingest_agent }}
    name: image:{{ file_ingest_agent }}
    source: pull

This results in an error stating:

fatal: []: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3.8"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Error pulling image image:sometag - 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=sometag&fromImage=image: Internal Server Error ("Get \https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)")"}

This seems to indicate it completely ignores the repository value and attempt to pull from http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=sometag&fromImage=image
I have tried a few variations of each of these, all with similar error results.
I would expect that the docker image from the private repo would be pulled down by the remote host the Ansible script is executing on.

Odd, from what I do see in the documentation of the module, platform should be nested under a pull dictionary. See the first example here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#examples. What is your version of this module/collection; of Ansible?

@β.εηοιτ.βε you are linking the docker_image module documentation. OP is using docker_image_pull (added in v3.6.0 of the collection)

Well seen, @Zeitounator, OP used the two modules, I did see only one ><.

Then from the Name format must be one of name, repository/name, or registry_server:port/name., I would probably infer that not having the registry port makes it think the example.com/some/path/to is a repository when example.com is a registry? Have you tried adding the port explicitly?

@β.εηοιτ.βε currently running core 2.16.6 with pip tracking 9.5.1. I tried using platform with a nested pull, but got a similar error. Once again, a 500 error trying to fetch from "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/". I figured that portion was not necessary due to this line: # Select platform for pulling. If not specified, will pull whatever docker prefers.
As for your second suggestion regaring using a port in the URL, attempted that (thanks for the suggestion) and got a new error :D
This time, a 400 error, calling out a Bad Request (\"invalid reference format\")
